# C# MVC Core.Net 2.1 Un Layout compartido entre diferentes proyectos web en una misma solución

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, layout, .net-core

En C# .Net Core 2.1 actualmente tengo una solución compuesta por varios proyectos web(MVC) y estas se deben administrar en un frente común, es decir que se debe navegar por las paginas de los diferentes proyectos desde una sola aplicación. Es aquí donde surge mi duda, ya que no puedo compartir un único layout entre mis diferentes proyectos, esto con el fin de tener una misma apariencia visual para toda la aplicacion.

Intente crear el layout en el proyecto web1 y este mismo llamarlo en el archivo _ViewStar.cshtml de la siguiente manera, pero el sistema me indica que no es capaz de encontrar el archivo layout.:

Codigo de mi _ViewStar.cshtml del proyecto web #1 (layout fuente para todos los demas proyectos):

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Este primero funciona y muestra el diseño sin problema en la aplicación.

Código de mi _ViewStar.cshtml del proyecto web #2

```
@{
    Layout = "~/NombreSolucion/ProyectoWeb2/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

El motivo de tener varios proyectos web en la misma solución es que el cliente lo solicito así y no puedo cambiar esta arquitectura.

Lo que busco es no repetir el código y los componentes del layout en cada uno de los proyectos web, ya que a futuro cualquier cambio se tendría que replicar en cada proyecto.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de asp.net core 2.1 existen las Librerías de Razor las cuales pueden contener vistas, páginas, controladores que pueden ser reutilizados por múltiples proyectos web.

Hice una prueba rápida creando una librería, referenciándola en ambos proyectos y eliminando `_Layout.cshtml` también de ambos y funcionó.  Puedes seguir la documentación para ver como crear librerías de este tipo:   https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas el archivo .cshtml fisicamente en el proyecto para poder referenciarlo, se me ocurre que podrias definirlo en un proyecto y despues usar la opcion `Add as Link` para agregarlo en los otros proyectos, entonces todos apuntaran al mismo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intente retirar el Layout del proyecto web #2 y seguir las indicaciones, pero me presenta el siguiente error, a pesar de que puedo acceder al archivo que se agrego(quedo en la carpeta Views/Shared del proyecto web 2).

InvalidOperationException: The layout view '/Views/_Layout.cshtml' could not be located. The following locations were searched:
/Views/_Layout.cshtml